# For what value of k is the system of equations consistent?

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

For

$$x − y + 2z = −2$$
$$2x + 3y + 4z = 7$$
$$4x − 7y + 5z = k$$
$$8x − 4y + 6z = 2$$

Using Gaussian Elimination, I first get the below by applying $R2 - 2R1$, $R3 - 4R1$, $R4 - 8R1$

\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&2&-2\\
0&5&0&11\\
0&-3&-3&k+8\\
0&4&-10&18\\
\end{bmatrix}

Then $R3 + \frac{3}{5}R2$ and $R4 - \frac{4}{5}R2$

\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&2&-2\\
0&5&0&11\\
0&0&-3&k+\frac{73}{5}\\
0&0&-10&\frac{46}{5}\\
\end{bmatrix}

Finally, $R4 -\frac{10}{3}R3$

\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&2&-2\\
0&5&0&11\\
0&0&-3&k+\frac{73}{5}\\
0&0&0&\frac{-10k}{3} - \frac{-146}{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}

So for the system to be consistent, $k = -14.6$?

I have performed the calculations a number of times and came to different values of $k$ but this one appeared the most times so I think it is the correct answer?

Comment: Not to be that guy, but you should not wager that your answer is correct because it shows up the most times; take your time with the computation and make sure you make no mistakes! That is the only way to be sure you have the correct answer. Other than that, If you are looking for confirmation that your answer is correct you can use an online resource like Wolfram Alpha to check your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it a bit simpler, consider equations

$$x − y + 2z = −2$$
$$2x + 3y + 4z = 7$$
$$8x − 4y + 6z = 2$$

Solve them for $x, y, z$ and plug the computed values into $$4x − 7y + 5z$$. If the initial system is to be consistent, $k$ must equal the computed value.

Comment: Brilliant, trying this, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that solved it. Thanks a lot.